# How to create a custom decimal format field in Sharepoint

Tags: site-column

I want to create a custom decimal format field in Sharepoint with structure `#####.#####`. Example: If you enter `1.05` this field will return `00001.05000`

Answer (score 1):

```
    =TEXT( 1.5 , "00000.00000")
```

In a Calculated Column Formula

Or in JavaScript

```
    String.format( "{0:#####.#####}" , 1.5 );
```

(*I have not tested this last syntax, google 'MSDN String format'*)

Answer (score 0):

Create a SharePoint field with the type 'Number' and in the additional settings you have an option to specify number of decimal places you may use it.
So whenever you add a number say 1.05 you will get 1.0500.
To get something like 0001.0500, you should do something with JavaScript as below.

Embed the below script DispForm of your list

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var a=$('td.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader').filter(function() { return $(this).text() === "Decimal Number"; }).parent().parent().find("td.ms-formbody").text().trim();
    var html=$('td.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader').filter(function() { return $(this).text() === "Decimal Number"; }).parent().parent().find("td.ms-formbody").html();
    var parent=$('td.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader').filter(function() { return $(this).text() === "Decimal Number"; }).parent().parent().find("td.ms-formbody").parent();
    var input=a;
    var output=a;
    a=a.split('.');
    var length = a[0].length;
    if(length<4){
        for(i=0;i<4-length;i++){
            output="0"+output;
        }
    }
    html=html.replace(input,output);
    $('td.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader').filter(function() { return $(this).text() === "Decimal Number"; }).parent().parent().find("td.ms-formbody").remove();
    $("<td width='350' class='ms-formbody' id='SPFieldNumber' vAlign='top'>"+html+"</td>").appendTo(parent);
});
</script>
```

Embed the below script EditForm of your list

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var a=$('td.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader nobr').filter(function() { return $(this).text() === "Decimal Number"; }).parent().parent().parent().find("td.ms-formbody input").val();
    var html=$('td.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader nobr').filter(function() { return $(this).text() === "Decimal Number"; }).parent().parent().parent().find("td.ms-formbody").html();
    var parent=$('td.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader nobr').filter(function() { return $(this).text() === "Decimal Number"; }).parent().parent().parent().find("td.ms-formbody").parent();
    var input=a;
    var output=a;
    a=a.split('.');
    var length = a[0].length;
    if(length<4){
        for(i=0;i<4-length;i++){
            output="0"+output;
        }
    }
    html=html.replace(input,output);
    $('td.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader nobr').filter(function() { return $(this).text() === "Decimal Number"; }).parent().parent().parent().find("td.ms-formbody").remove();
    $("<td width='350' class='ms-formbody' vAlign='top'>"+html+"</td>").appendTo(parent);
});
</script>
```

Note: Replace the 'Decimal Number' with your column name.